# Xcode upload error: "validateAssets (1272)"?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

Trying to upload build to itunesConnect, and getting this error from Xcode.
Not sure what this error is about? validateAssets 1272?

My Xcode 11.2.1

Tried Transporter app - same story.

Comment: i just started getting this too, about 15 minutes ago and was just about to make a stackoverflow post about it.  Maybe it is something on their end?

Comment: Outage https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 1):

This error started to happen to me today from 1:00 am. It seems, that it's a bug on their side. We can just wait. Good, that you share your problem with us. Now i can go sleep and try to send build in the morning :)

BTW, you can check apple's system statuses here: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ (thx [MAGiGO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4709057/magigo))